# Is 6 the smallest index for an irreducible subfactor to have a principal graph with a multiplicity >1 edge?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

The irreducible subfactor $(R^{S_3} \subset R)$, of index $6$, admits a principal graph with a multiplicity $2$ edge because the group $S_3$ admits an irreducible complex representation of dimension $2$.

The same for the subfactor $(R \subset M_2(R))$, of index $4$, but it is not irreducible.

*Question*: Is $6$ the smallest index for an irreducible subfactor to have a principal graph with an edge of multiplicity $>1$?

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level- / arXiv tag to give this question more visibility.